# Embedding a PowerBI report inside a SharePoint page using “Publish to Web” Vs using “Embed in SP online”

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, reports, powerbi

I have a free account for PowerBI, and i did the following, to test how i can embed a PowerBI report inside sharepoint pages (sharepoint on-premises + sharepoint On-line):-

1. I create a new PowerBI report using the PowerBI desktop tool.
2. Where I defined to use a custom SharePoint list as the source.
3. The i Saved >> Publish the PowerBI report.

Now I want to show the PowerBI report inside my SharePoint pages, where i have the following 2 farms:-

1. SharePoint on-premises
2. SharePoint online.

Now since i am using a free account for the PowerBI (as currently i am testing its features), so I can only do the following inside the PowerBI **“Publish to Web”**. While the second option **“Embed in a SharePoint online”** is not available for free accounts. Here are the 2 options for Pro users (currently my user is a free account for PowerBI, so not all options are available to me).

[image]

Then inside my SP online & SP on-premises farms, i did the following:-

1. Create a new page.
2. I add an Embed Code to the page.

[image]

3. Inside the code snippet , I add the code generated from the “PowerBi >> “**Publish to Web**” option.
4. The code looks as follow:-

> ```
> <iframe 
> width="800" height="600" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=e*******9" 
> frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true">
> </iframe>
> ```

5. The result will be as follow, inside my page:-
   [image]

Now i am not sure about the following:-

1. what are the main differences between showing a PowerBI report inside my sharepoint pages using “**Publish to Web**” or using “**Embed in a SharePoint online**”??
2. from my reading that using “**Embed in a SharePoint online**” appraoch will only be available inside sharepoint online & using the Modern interface for the page.. but not sure if the final result will be the same for these 2 options “**Publish to Web**” & “**Embed in a SharePoint online**”?

Comment: Embed in SharePoint Online is for using the new PowerBI Web part made using the SharePoint Framework (SPFx). This web part is much more versatile than the iframe - it allows single sign on for instance. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Announcing-Power-BI-Web-Part-Preview-for-SharePoint/ba-p/43951

I don't know how to answer #2.

Comment: @KevinStone now "Publish to Web" will publish the powerBI report to the web and make it available for everyone. so any user can view this report, the user does not have to login to sharepoint on-line nor to PowerBI... but i am not sure if “Embed in a SharePoint online” will provide a more restricted/secure access.. now i can not test this as i am using a free powerBI user which does not provide “Embed in a SharePoint online” option.. but currently i am trying to figure out Why/How “Embed in a SharePoint online” provide a secure way to embed the powerBI report (as mentioned in its description)?